# Is it possible to make a portable password storing PHP code when magic_quotes_qpc is on?

Tags: php, passwords, magic-quotes, magic-quotes-gpc

I am developing my first website. My shared hosting provider has magic_quotes_qpc on and doesn't want to change it.
As I understand, there is a following problem with password storing:
1. User types in a value like "strong'password" into a registration form.
2. Php writes value "strong/'password" into a DB (or hash based on it).
3. When user wants to log in, he types "strong'password" as a password.
4. Php turns it into "strong/'password" - it is the same value like in DB, so user enters successfully.

And it will work fine until I change hosting provider to another one, without magic_quotes_qpc on. All such accounts will become broken.
Using stripslashes will make "strong/password" unstable.
Seems like I need to make single and double qutoes forbidden for using in a password.

Did I get the magic quotes algorithm right? If yes, any thoughts about this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to write code which works on both cases, you can use `get_magic_quotes_gpc` to check whether it's enabled.

When magic quotes is enabled, use `stripslashes` to get rid of the extra slashes, then handle the string as you would when it is not enabled.

Comment: Yes, strange that I was confused with that. Simple "if" statement resolves the problem.